# Configurar appender do Log4j para exibir no console log a partir de Error e salvar em arquivo logs a partir de Info

Tags: java, log4j

Boa noite pessoal.

Preciso exibir no console apenas logs a partir de Error e gravar em arquivo logs a partir de Info.

Já tentei utilizar a propriedade additivity para false, mas ao utilizá-la o o appender para de funcionar e também tentei usar respostas do Stackoverflow, mas não funcionou.

Dependência utilizada:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

log4j.category.debugLogger=INFO, debugLog
log4j.appender.debugLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.debugLog.File=debug.log
log4j.appender.debugLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debugLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n
```

HelloWorld.java:

```
package com.vaannila.helloworld;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloWorld {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("Sample debug message");
        logger.info("Sample info message");
        logger.warn("Sample warn message");
        logger.error("Sample error message");
        logger.fatal("Sample fatal message");
    }
}
```

A única forma que consegui foi definindo o rootLogger como Info e um appender com um log acima, mas o que necessito é o contrário.

Há uma forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na configuração do log4j `log4j.properties`

Para configurá-lo corretamente recomendo definir em `rootLogger` sempre o level mais baixo (`DEBUG`) para todos os appenders que você vai utilizar, ai quando você for configurar cada appender utilizar o `Threshold` para especificar o nível que o appender irá aderir.

Acho que a configuração a seguir vai resolver seu problema:

```
#Cria os dois appender para o nível mais baixo de log
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console, file

#Configura o console appender
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

#Configura o fileAppender
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.file.File=debug.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n
```